# Adding class conditionally inside Form::text() in Laravel Collective

Tags: php, laravel, forms

I'm using Laravel Collective for my forms, and whenever the validation fails for a field, I need to add a class. The default field looks like this:

```
{{ Form::text('name', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
```

Whenever validation fails, I need to add `border-danger` to the class:

```
{{ Form::text('name', null, ['class' => 'form-control border-danger']) }}
```

But I cannot simply do `@if ($errors->has('name'))` inside that `{{ Form }}` field.

Is there any simple way to accomplish this? One thing I don't want to do is somthing like this:

```
@if ($errors->has('name'))

{{ Form::text('name', null, ['class' => 'form-control border-danger']) }}

@else

{{ Form::text('name', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}

@endif
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use ternary operator like below

```
{{ Form::text('name', null, ['class' => 'form-control '.($errors->has('name') ? 'border-danger':'')]) }}
```

Use brackets to execute ternary operator first .

Comment: I always keep forgetting about the ternary operator.. :) thnx